# How does one include a MP4 within a pdf via Media9 and TexShop?

Tags: media9

Here's my MWE:
Based on http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/media9/media9.pdf

[Only a non-clickable button appears, no errors for media9 in Console, other similar queries are from antiquity, thx!]

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}


\includemedia[
  label=some_dice,
  width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.45\linewidth,
  addresource=VID00727.MP4,
  transparent,
  activate=pageopen,
  passcontext,
  flashvars={
    source=VID00727.MP4
   &loop=true
  }
]{}{VPlayer.swf}
% loop video
\mediabutton[
  mediacommand=some_dice:playPause,
  overface=\color{blue}{\fbox{\strut Play/Pause}},
  downface=\color{red}{\fbox{\strut Play/Pause}}
]{\fbox{\strut Play/Pause}}
\mediabutton[
  mediacommand=some_dice:setSource [(VID00727.MP4)]
]{\fbox{\strut VID00727.MP4}}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: From the package documentation: "Playback of multimedia files uses Adobe Flash Player, which was bundled with Adobe Reader 9 and 10 versions. Unfortunately, beginning with Adobe Reader 11, it must be installed as a separate plug-in." Could this be the reason for your issue?